# Unable to get details for a place using Google Places API - "Cannot invoke 'lookUpPlaceID' "

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm trying to get details about a place using the Google Places API for iOS. When attempt to call the `lookUpPlaceID` function, receiving the following Swift compiler error:

> Cannot invoke 'lookUpPlaceID' with an argument list of type '(String, callback: (GMSPlace!, _) -> Void)'

```
    let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"

    placesClient!.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place: GMSPlace!, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if place != nil {
            println("Place name \(place.name)")
            println("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            println("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
            println("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        } else {
            println("No place details for \(placeID)")
        }
    })
```

I'm using the example code available in the Google Places API documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/places/ios/place-details#get-place

The placesClient is an object of type GMSPlacesClient. Earlier in the code, I am able to successfully call the placesClient autcompleteQuery function, so I don't think it's a problem with my placesClient.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the callback, you need to replace the type (`GMSPlace`) with the variable name that you want to use, which you correctly did for `error`.

It should be something like:

```
let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"

placesClient!.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println("lookup place id query error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let p = place {
        println("Place name \(p.name)")
        println("Place address \(p.formattedAddress)")
        println("Place placeID \(p.placeID)")
        println("Place attributions \(p.attributions)")
    } else {
        println("No place details for \(placeID)")
    }
})
```

Also, make sure to unwrap those optional variables (both place and error) before using them, by doing force unwrapping (!), like I did for `error` above, or by using `if let`, like I did for `place`.

Hope this helps.